# ColorGrid exception while panning or zooming with CenteredPoints = true

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

Good morning,

I am using Steema TeeChart for .NET 2012 Evaluation 4.1.2012.02284, and I am programming in MSVS 2010 C#...

I set up a ColorGrid, but when I set MyColorGrid.CenteredPoints = true, I sometimes get an exception when I zoom in, or pan, using the mouse. Is there a downloadable version in which this phenomenon does not occur, or is there something I can do to fix this problem?

Please feel free to let me know if I have left out any important details....

Thank you.

JDDK

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple code and using next code in latest version, the exception doesn't appear for me:

```
 Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ColorGrid colorgrid1;
        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
            colorgrid1 = new ColorGrid(tChart1.Chart);
            colorgrid1.FillSampleValues();
            colorgrid1.CenteredPoints = true;

        }
```

For this reason, I recommend you download last evaluation version of 31st of January build number 4.1.2012.01310 of TeeChartFor.Net that you can download [here](http://www.steema.com/download/net), and check again if the problem persist in your application. If you problem persist please, try to modify my code because can reproduce exactly the problem here and try to find a good solution for you.

Thank you,

Comment: I downloaded that exact version (after I have tried a version just older than that), and it did the trick. Thank you!